# Set default value of dropdownlist based on datasource

Tags: asp.net, html-select

I have a webform that uses a dropdownlist to populate a gridview.  The dropdown list is bound to a datasource.  I would like to have the default value of the dropdown list be a value in the listing.  I have a series of 5 values, one of which is actually a blank.  The default value I am looking for would be index 2 or the value "Agency Error"

Here is the query I have for the datasource:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [AnnoType] FROM [AnnoType]
```

Is there a way to do this?

I am just trying to eliminate one of maybe 50 clicks the user needs to do in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectedIndex` property

```
dropdownlist.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

or `SelectedValue` property

```
dropdownlist.SelectedValue = dropdownlist.Items.FindByText("Agency Error").Value;
```

Comment: Do I add this in the page load after the bind data.

Comment: @TimVavra: yes, you should do this after binding of data.